# Save user data in another table once a user is created in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in django. I am using django 1.10 with `allauth` app which takes care of frontend registration, sending user confirmation email,validation, login with email etc.

The allauth app inserts three rows in three tables when a user is created.

```
1. auth_user
2. account_emailaddress
3. account_emailconfirmation
```

When adding a user from admin it creates a row in `auth_user` and `general_userprofile` table. I would like to insert a row in `account_emailaddress` table when admin creates a user.

Fields in account_emailaddress are--

```
id
email
verified
primary
user_id
```

The models.py looks like --

```
class EmailAddress(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name ='address')
    email = models.EmailField()
    verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('verified'), default=True)
    primary = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('primary'), default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'account_emailaddress'


class UserProfile(models.Model, HashedPk):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, related_name ='profile')
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=False, default="")
    website = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField( blank=True, null=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        EmailAddress.objects.create(user=instance
```

)

Forms.py look like this

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Div, Field
from ajax_select.fields import AutoCompleteSelectField, AutoCompleteField
from phonenumber_field.formfields  import PhoneNumberField
from . import models
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField


class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(label=_("Phone (Please state your country code eg. +44)"))
    organisation = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    captcha = ReCaptchaField(attrs={'theme' : 'clean'})


    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        """
        profile, created = models.UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        profile.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        profile.organisation = self.cleaned_data['organisation']
        profile.save()
        user.save()
        """
        up = user.profile
        up.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        up.organisation = self.cleaned_data['organisation']
        user.save()
        up.save()
```

How can I get the user id and email which is created under class `EmailAddress` and save it to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you want to store user id and email in your EmailAdress table you must had these fields in your model.

After this, when your handler receives the user creation signal, you can add something like this in it.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        EmailAdress.objects.create(user_id = instance.id, user_email=instance.email)
```

Comment: Many thanks. First things first I need to get the email and user field in the model. I will come back to you.

Comment: The data is saving in the table but for some reason the model is not getting email value. How can I pass the email value to the table.

Comment: Please post your User and EmailAdress model.

Comment: I have updated the post with models.py and forms.py. There is userprofile model in models.py but no user model.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. The main purpose of this question is resolved. I will do a bit research on how I can fetch the email data inside the model.

Comment: Basically your instance variable is an instance of your User class. To access email value, you just need the email property of your instance, something like instance.email

Comment: All good. It works now. I had to `EmailAddress.objects.create(user=instance, email=instance.email)`